# Given "A implies B", is "B implies A" "the other hand" or "the other side"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request, mathematics

I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/421414/244425) just now, where

> `x = 2` **→** `x² = 4`  is true
>
> where "**→**" means "implies", `x = 2` "implies" `x² = 4`,
>
> on the other hand, `x² = 4` does not "imply" `x = 2` in general, where
>   the counterexample is `x = -2`

This is an "image version", since ell.stackexchange does not support Tex command.

[image]

In that question, is it reasonable to say "B implies A" or

[image]

as "the other hand"?

Is "the other side" or some other expression better?

Comment: In addition to _conversely_, you may also use _the converse_ (a noun) to refer to the proposition you mentioned, e.g. "x=2 implies x^2=4, but the converse is not true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use "conversely":

> If n is even then n squared is also even. Conversely, if n-squared is even, then n is even.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "If n is even then n squared is also even" seems to not to be a true proposition, consider 6 is even ...

Comment: so 36 is also even... however the correctness or not of my maths doesn't affect the choice of word.

Comment: You are right, I've accepted and upvoted it. Would please take a look at this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/220419/95385)